# Convert video of any format to mp4 using php and ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

After doing some online searches, I found out that ffmpeg is the best way to convert any video format to mp4. How can I install the ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php extensions on my dedicated server?

Comment: you should ask this on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com) as it's not a programming question. Also, you should tell others which operating system you run on the dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following commands to install FFMPEG & codec libraries:

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

sudo apt-get install libavcodec-unstripped-52

I am not sure of the php extensions.

Regards, Vibgyor